# Obtain Full Path of Copied File from Finder (Without special copy command)

Tags: finder, bash

When copying a file in Finder (Command + C) and pasting it (Command + V) in iTerm2 or Terminal the full path of the file gets pasted. I wanted to use this in a script by calling `pbpaste` but this only returned the file name part, not the file.

Cmd-V and `pbpaste` both access the clipboard but apparantly in different ways. So how can I get the path of the file selected with Cmd-C in a shell script?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here with the information on how iTerm2 works?

Comment: “Using a different copy command is not required for iterm2....”. Finder, iTerm2 and `pbcopy` are three totally different things.   `pbcopy` is not going to do what Finder does because they are literally in very different environments of macOS

Comment: Did you mean to write "`pbpaste`only..."?

Comment: I mentioned iTerm2, as it proofs that it is possible. But how do they do it?

Comment: In order to apply python/bash/js scripts to files that I copied from Finder, I would like to obtain their full path.

Comment: I have the same question. I only found a workaround which you already dismissed. I mention it for the record: Using Cmd-Option-C in the Finder makes the full path accessible with `pbpaste`. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67663605))